# Best way to create custom list layout in Android

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, imageview

i am new to Android. I need to create a layout having list views along with textview and image icons. Please refer the attached screenshot and give me suggestion that how can i achieve this?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: you can implement the customized adapter

Comment: I'd use a TextView with a compoundDrawable (drawableTop), for better performances. This drawable has to be set to a StateList selector, since you want it to change its color.

Comment: Thanks to all.. i got the way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a custom list view you need to follow some simple steps :

1. create the xml layout of one row of your list_view and the xml layout for the main activity including in it the listView control
2. create a custom adapter for the custom listview that allows you to get the texts and images in your custom ListView and change them
3. attach your data (as an arraylist) to the listView

I won't give you the code in this post, instead I will give you a very detailed tutorial that for me is the most straightforward to create what you want to achieve : [Create custom listview tutorial](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

Comment: Thanks @Yasmine..It is helpful.

Comment: @YasmineGreenApple i need to place imageview above the textview, please help me in this concern

Comment: @Anand Gautam : you can place your views wherever you want, in you listview row layout you can place a linear_layout with orientation:vertical and place your imageView first then your textView, that's the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent tutorial to do just like that -

*Implement the `customListView` using `BaseAdapter`. 
In `CustomListView` show the `ImageView`with `TextView` for each list item.*

**Check ==>** [custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android](http://www.caveofprogramming.com/frontpage/articles/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android/).

The display -

[image]